# The picture of the dog from Work From Home banner

Tags: support, jobs, advertising

I really like this dog form the "Work. From Home" banner, and I want to have it as a full picture without the text, but I can't find it :(
Is there a clean version of it?

[image]

Comment: Off-topic since it's about wanting a free copy of a licensed image

Comment: Out of curiosity, when did you see this ad the last time?

Comment: Surely wanting a free copy of a licensed image does not make it off topic, it just makes it an invalid request due to legalities - but can be answered?

Comment: I thought you were going to ask to buy the dog... -1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]
<sub>(source: [dogslife.com.au](http://www.dogslife.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/iStock_000015399914Medium.jpg))</sub>

([Uploaded as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JArDX.jpg) to prevent image rot)

Comment: Nice find @Martijn, I didn't bother to look for the actual source.

Comment: Source: http://www.istockphoto.com/photo/beagle-looking-at-the-laptop-9153677?st=c1e7607

Comment: while we are at it, can you also find the cat one :3

Comment: @Borislav [tag:status-error-cat-not-found]

Comment: is this some lame joke?

Comment: @Borislav yup, kind of.